# session isn't closed exception inside nifi custom processor

Tags: java, apache-nifi

want to get file and use it's xml content and then update one of it's tag but something wents wrong more clearly ffstream=session(flowfile) which is later closed ffstream.close() doesn't close actually and throws exception,here is my code what should i change?

```
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile,"filename",file.getName() + ".xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(ffStream);
ffStream.close();
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList myNodeList = (NodeList) xPath.compile("//runAs/text()")
    .evaluate(flowFile, XPathConstants.NODESET);myNodeList.item(0).setNodeValue("false");
FlowFile flowFile2=session.create();
flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile2,"filename","config" + ".xml");
session.write(flowFile2, new OutputStreamCallback() {
    @Override
    public void process(final OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = null;
        try {
            transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamResult result=new StreamResult(bos);
        try {
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte []array=bos.toByteArray();
        out.write(array);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not show the creation or initialization of ffStream, are you using ffStream = session.read(flowFile)?  If so, once you call putAttribute(), the input stream you had open for previous version of the flow file is no longer valid, because you have created a newer version with your call to putAttribute().

You have some issues after that as well. For example, you end up creating a new flow file, but then use the original flow file's pointer/variable to refer to it after the session.write(). That can definitely cause problems. If you want to overwrite the incoming flow file, use session.write() with a StreamCallback rather than an OutputStreamCallback. If you want to keep the incoming flow file and create a new one, I recommend maintaining a single variable for each flow file (flowFile and flowFile2) and updating that variable every time you update that file (via session.write, session.putAttribute, etc.)

Comment: i created  ffstream  like this Inputsteam  ffstream=session.read(flowfile)

Comment: did  you mean that  i can't  get xmlDocument  beacause previuous session is  closed?

Comment: what  should i do  to  get this  xmldocument and  write it in flowfile2 , or  is  it better  to write  updated  flowfile into  flowfile?

Comment: bad  practice is  writing  this  code  inside  session.write:

Comment: i mean this ..ransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(); 
Transformer transformer = null; 
try {

Comment: or catching xmlDocument  and  using  it as a source?

Comment: Are you trying to overwrite the incoming flow file's content, or output the incoming flow file as well as the altered one?

Comment: I am trying to change the  value of one xml document tag  and  then overwrite it

Answer (score 1):

I  have  removed  .putAttribute() and also  closed  ffstream session  after  reading xml document in session.write()  function  and  i t worked  perfectly.

```
InputStream ffStream=session.read(flowFile);
DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(ffStream);

XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
XPathExpression myNodeList = (XPathExpression) xPath.compile("/localAttributes");

Node nodeGettingChanged = (Node) myNodeList.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
NodeList childNodes = nodeGettingChanged.getChildNodes();
for (int i = 0; i != childNodes.getLength(); ++i)
{
    Node child = childNodes.item(i);
    if (!(child instanceof Element))
        continue;

    if (child.getNodeName().equals("runAs"))
        child.getFirstChild().setNodeValue("false") ;
}

session.write(flowFile, new StreamCallback() {
    @Override
    public void process(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = null;
        try {
            transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
        ffStream.close();
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);
        try {
            transformer.transform(source, result);
        } catch (TransformerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
        outputStream.write(array);
    }
});
```